# Sumar Columnas seleccionadas en un datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Buen dia,estoy sumando 1 columna llamada "TOP_PUNTAJE" dependiendo si doy clic en el checkbox, en caso se quite la seleccion este contador regrese a su valor anterior.

He realizado este metodo pero funciona al seleccionar la fila con la tecla CTRL+CLIC todo funciona bien,pero no es lo que necesito.

por favor alguna idea en que parte del codigo puedo modifcar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo aplicado:

```js
  Private Sub dgvproductoscanjes_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvproductoscanjes.CellClick
       
        Dim CantFilas As Integer = dgvproductoscanjes.SelectedRows.Count
        Dim Indices As Integer() = New Integer(CantFilas - 1) {}
        Dim Contador As Integer = 0
        Dim Suma As Double = 0

        For Each Fila As DataGridViewRow In dgvproductoscanjes.SelectedRows


            Indices(Contador) = Fila.Index


            Contador += 1
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To CantFilas - 1
            Suma += Double.Parse(dgvproductoscanjes.Rows(Indices(i)).Cells(2).Value.ToString())
        Next

        lblpuntos.Text = Suma
     
    End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: con el codigo publicado solo funciona al seleccionar la fila si presiono la tecla CTRL + clic,pero lo que deseo es como hacerlo cuando seleccione o de clic en el check box,como podia acoplar el codigo para cuando se haga clic en los checkbox entiendo que se realiza en el evento clic del datagriview

Comment: ¿Estás diciendo que haciendo sólo click sin la tecla CTRL no hace la suma ni siquiera de ese campo?

Comment: talvez no me dejo entender,la suma funciona solo al dar CTRL + clic,pero lo estoy tratando de realizar es que esa suma funcione al dar clic en el checbox

Comment: Ok Kenny eso lo entiendo, lo que quiero saber es ¿Qué pasa (si pasa algo) cuando das click sin la tecla CTRL?

Comment: ok,solo pasa el valor de la columna TOP_PUNTOS dependiendo de lo que selecciones.

Comment: Te pregunto eso porque creo que no puedes comenzar desde cero 0 el conteo de las filas, si mal no recuerdo debes hacerlo desde 1 ya que cero es para los títulos de la tabla. Ya hace como 5 años que dejé de programar en VB y C, ahora estoy en diseño web pero recuerdo bien algunas cosas

Comment: Fíjate que la variable Indices la inicializaste con el total de filas -1, eso me hace pensar que el valor 0 es el índice de la fila donde aparecen los títulos

Comment: mmm ok tiene logica tu punto,te felicito por el acenso que as tenido yo recien estoy en pañales jejeje,bueno probare

Comment: Lo otro que veo kenny es que el código se realiza cada vez que haces click en alguna celda del dgv, eso quiere decir que cuando haces click en la 1ra. celda se ejecuta todo el código y allí "muere", luego cuando haces click en la 2da. celda el código se vuelve a ejecutar inicializando todas las variables, entonces Contador y Suma no acumulan nada, siempre estarán en cero

Comment: entiendo esa parte,pero lo curioso que si selecciono toda la fila con la tecla CTRL+clic si suma jajajja , seguire analizando el codigo en algo estoy fallando.